# Metric space -globes

Tags: real-analysis

Let (S; ρ) be a metric space.
1). Prove that if ε< δ, then Gp(ε) ⊆ Gp(δ) holds for all p ε S.

2). True or false? If Gp(ε) = Gp(δ) then ε= δ

I need some verification on my answer. Please could someone point out the improvements needed on  the answer.

- My answer

1). let 0 < ε < δ
Claim Gp(ε) ⊆ Gp(δ)
Let: x ε Gp(ε)
P(x, p) < ε implies that P(x, p) < δ

Since  P(x, p) < ε implies that P(x, p) < δ  thus it can be claimed that ε < δ

Gp(ε) ⊆ Gp(δ)

2). True since Gp(ε) = Gp(δ) will be globes of same radius then ε= δ.

Comment: You really should learn how to use latex codes. For instance, to get $G_p(\epsilon)$ you type G_p(\epsilon) between dollar signs.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss. I have just started to use it and still learning. i have used MSword. Thank you for your advise. Could the latex codes be directly typed in the MSE answer box or there is some other procedures to follow.

Comment: you just type the latex codes between dollar signs as you are typing your post.

Comment: Thank you ittay you have been very helpful.

Comment: So my answer given above needs some improvement right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working more rigorously:

It is given that $\epsilon <\delta$. Let $x\in G_p(\epsilon)$. Then, by definition of globe, it follows that $\rho (x,p)<\epsilon$. But then it holds that $\rho (x,p)<\epsilon <\delta$ and thus, again by definition of globe, it holds that $x\in G_p(\delta)$. This establishes that $G_p(\epsilon)\subseteq G_p(\delta)$.

As for the second claim, it is false. Think about discrete metric spaces.

Comment: For discrete matrix Gp(a) = Gp(b) but there is a possibility that a is not equal to b. Eg. Gp(3) = Gp (2) but 3 is not equal to 2